# not able to get particular table cell value

Tags: jquery

I have a code to get the rejected qty on table when ever user entered accepted qty. But at particular cell alone i am not able to get the accepted qty value.

```js
$(document).on("keydown", "#accqty", function(e) {
  if (e.which == 9) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
    alert(item);
    var accepted = parseFloat($("#accqty").val());
    var received = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').text();
    alert("accepted   " + accepted);
    alert("received   " + received);
    var rejected = 0;
    if (accepted <= received) {
      rejected = received - accepted;
      row.find("td:eq(6) input[type='text']").val(rejected);
    } else {
      alert("Accepted qty can not be more than received; Please chcek!");
    }

    if (rejected > 0) {
      row.find("td:eq(6) input[type='text']").removeClass('tb1').addClass('reject');
    }
  }
});
```

For example. i have two rows in my table. for first row i could retrieve the value of accepted qty using accqty id. but for second row, accepted qty is coming null if first row accepted qty has no value or No value or get the accepted qty from first row if its present. Please some one help. Note my table will be loaded dynamically.

```js
$.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
  var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
  rowNew.children().eq(0).append(i);
  rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['itemcode']);
  rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['itemname']);
  rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['receivedqty']);
  rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<input type="text"  id="inspdate"/>');
  rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text"  id="accqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>');
  rowNew.children().eq(6).html('<input type="text"  id="rejqty" class="reject"/>');
  rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<input type="text"  id="rema"/>');
  rowNew.appendTo($tbody);
  i++;
});
```

So accepted qty always taking from first row

Comment: a fiddle would be nice

Comment: **Ids need to be unique**, if you have multiple ids that are the same then the js will only pick up the first id and all remaining ones will be ignored

Comment: @Pete: Thanks for your valuable comments! Could you please suggest me an alternative way to get corresponding row value

Comment: use a class and bind the event to the class - where you have `$("#accqty").val()`, you should be using `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

Use change input on particular table to get the row values as mentioned below

```js
$(document).ready(function()  {   
  $("#itemtable").on("change", "input", function() {
   var row = $(this).closest("tr");
       var received = parseFloat(row.find("td:eq(3)").text()); // get received qty
       var accepted = parseFloat($(row).find("td:eq(5) input[type='text']").val()); //get accepted qty
       
       if (received < accepted){
        alert("Accepted qty greater than received qty, Please check!");
       } else {
        var rejected = received - accepted;
        row.find("td:eq(6) input[type='text']").val(isNaN(rejected) ? "" : rejected); 
       }
       
       if (rejected > 0){
        row.find("td:eq(6) input[type='text']").removeClass('tb1').addClass('reject');  
       }
  });
});
```